# Mousewheel event - Velocity/Momentum

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently experimenting with a THREE.JS project, and using a mousewheel scroll event to go from 0 to 1.

However, I would like to achieve the same momentum that you see here at this link [playdoh by merci Michael](http://playdoh-lagaleriedesespeces.com)

At the moment, this is what I've done so far.

```
this.R = 0
mouseWheel(dx, dy) {
    if (this.R < 0) {
        this.R = 0
        return
    }
    if (this.R > 1) {
        this.R = 1
        return
    }

    inertia.update(dy)
    this.R += dy / 45500
    let clamped = this.clamp(0, 1, this.R);

    // UPDATE THREEJS CAMERA POS
    this.dolly.cameraPosition = clamped;
    this.dolly.lookatPosition = clamped;
    this.dolly.update();
}
clamp(min, max, v) {
    if (v < min) {
        return min;
    } else if (v > max) {
        return max;
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}
```

It works, but doesn't achieve the same effect in the example link I sent.  I'd like the person to scroll, and have it with some velocity so it continues to scroll more.  At the moment, when you scroll, it just stops almost immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of

```
this.dolly.cameraPosition = clamped;
```

something like

```
this.dolly.cameraPosition += (clamped-this.dolly.cameraPosition)*0.5
```

instead?

You can change the 0.5 to different values like 0.1 or 0.9 to change the snappiness of the transition.